# How do I verify that files have been uploaded?

Tags: php, upload

I used this code to find the temporary location of files(pictures) that users(me) upload to my site using a php upload script.

```
 echo sys_get_temp_dir();
```

returns

> C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp

When I look in the temp folder I see some files with .tmp so I don't know if they are the ones downloaded.  I'm trying to troubleshoot my PHP upload script. This is because I want to first verify the actual files are downloaded before I use the php move function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [is_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php). The `$_FILES` superglobal has information as well. And finally, the whole section about [file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function.